# First order non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me solve this first-order non-linear differential equation.

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{y+xy^2}{x-5y+y^2 \mathrm{cos}(y)}$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. It is here mandatory to give your own thoughts and ideas on problems. What have you tried here? Have you solved any similar problems? What methods are you familiar with? If you answer those questions, it will be more likely that you get better help. In this particular example, I guess one would be happy to obtain an equation $f(x,y)=0$ that describes the solutions.

Comment: How do you suggest that we help?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Written as $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y+xy^2}{x-5y+y^2 \cos(y)}$$ the differential equation seems extremely complex because of the simultaneous presence of $y$ and $\cos(y)$.

So, let us reverse it and write it as $$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{x-5y+y^2 \cos(y)}{y+xy^2}$$ Now, because of the denominator, let us make a change of variable $x=z-\frac 1 y$ (which makes $y+xy^2=y^2z$), $\frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{dz}{dy}+\frac{1}{y^2}$. So, in terms of $z$, the differential equation write (after minor simplifications) $$\frac{\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{5}{y}-\cos (y)}{z}+\frac{dz}{dy}=0$$ which seems to be quite simple.

I am sure that you can take from here.